# Access form objects from a partial class

Tags: c#, .net, forms, winforms

I have a form that makes use of a lot of controls. Some of the logic behind these controls are in other classes.

Other elements of the logic are so directly tied to objects on the form (list boxes, labels, buttons, etc.) that it just makes sense to keep it in the form's designer.cs file. The amount of code is getting too large for me to manage in the designer.cs file so I want to break that code into a partial class. I also want that partial class to have unfettered access to any object in the form.

Unfortunately I cannot seem to access the form's controls. First, here is what I have in place for my test (using the out-of-box creation of a new project in Visual Studio 2015):

Form1.cs

```
namespace Project1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Form1.Designer.cs

```
partial class Form1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// lots of other code generated by Visual Studio...
```

... Later in Form1.Designer.cs

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
```

And here comes the problem in my custom partial class files called Form1.MoreCode.cs

```
namespace Project1
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        label1. //nope!
    }
}
```

As you can see, I made an attempt to access the form object named "label1" in the designer.cs file but could not. I tried making the label itself public, then I tried making all the classes public like this:

```
public partial class form1
```

... And like this:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
```

I did a lot of research with little help. Someone else on Stack Overflow suggests my approach should work but unless I missed something important, it does not.

Also in my research, some people suggest you can create properties for objects. I really do not want to do that because I just want to have regular, normal access to the objects without having to do all those additional steps (might defeat the purpose of splitting out the code in the first place).

Could you please tell me if what I am trying to do is possible? If so, what is the approach I should take in order to make this work properly?

Thanks.

Comment: in the designer.. change the  access level of the label from `private to public`

Comment: or even just to `protected` should do

Comment: Are you trying to write code directly in the class? Not in a function?

Comment: @MethodMan not necessary; it's a partial class - i.e the same class.

Comment: you using label on the class level - nono

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write code directly in a class, partial or not. Put your code in a method:

```
namespace Project1
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        label1. //nope!

        public void CodeGoesInHere()
        {
            label1.Text = "hello"; // yep!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was missing!